# Apply a custom rolling function with arguments on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

I have this `df` (here is the `df.head()`):

```
    date        colA
0   2018-01-05  0.6191
1   2018-01-20  0.5645
2   2018-01-25  0.5641
3   2018-01-27  0.5404
4   2018-01-30  0.4933
```

I would like to apply a function to every 3 rows recursively, meaning for rows: 1,2,3  then for rows: 2,3,4  then rows 3,4,5, etc.

This is what I wrote:

```
def my_rolling_func(df, val):
  
    p1 = (df['date']-df['date'].min()).dt.days.tolist()[0],df[val].tolist()[0]
    p2 = (df['date']-df['date'].min()).dt.days.tolist()[1],df[val].tolist()[1]
    p3 = (df['date']-df['date'].min()).dt.days.tolist()[2],df[val].tolist()[2]
  
    return sum([i*j for i,j in [p1,p2,p3]])

df.rolling(3,center=False,axis=1).apply(my_rolling_func, args=('colA'))
```

But I get this error:

> ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 494.

494 is the number of rows in my `df`.

I'm not sure why it says I passed a length of 1, I thought the rolling generate slices of `df` according to the window size I defined (3), and then it applied the function for that subset of `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you specified the wrong axis. Axis 1 means that the window will slide along the columns. You want the window to slide along the indexes, so you need to specify `axis=0`. Secondly, you misunderstand a little about how rolling works. It will apply your function to each column independently, so you cannot operate on both the `date` and `colA` columns at the same time inside your function.
I rewrote your code to make it work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-05', '2018-01-30', freq='D'), 'A': np.random.random((26,))})
df = df.set_index('date')


def my_rolling_func(s):
    days = (s.index - s.index[0]).days
    return sum(s*days)


res = df.rolling(3, center=False, axis=0).apply(my_rolling_func)

print(res)
```

```
Out: 
                  A
date                
2018-01-05       NaN
2018-01-06       NaN
2018-01-07  1.123872
2018-01-08  1.121119
2018-01-09  1.782860
2018-01-10  0.900717
2018-01-11  0.999509
2018-01-12  1.755408
2018-01-13  2.344914
       .....
```

Comment: Thanks, so the only way to operate with 2 columns is to create a new `df`  where one column is the index? and there is no way to operate on more than 2 columns with rolling?

Comment: See "method" parameter  on the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: I simplified my question to include 2 columns, but what I meant to multiple columns. I thought the solution for more than 1 column will be for all cases where `n_columns>1` but I guess I got an answer for that - not possible.. thanks